# How to configure PAT on Cisco router

Tags: nat, cisco

I have a little problem configuring my Cisco Router1 in Cisco Packet Tracer.
I want to ping my PC1 from my PC2, which is in a private network.

I have the following schema:

[image]

So, I configured my Router1 as followed:

```
Router1(config)#access-list 1 permit 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.3
Router1(config)#access-list 1 deny any
Router1(config)#ip nat pool nat_pool 155.0.0.2 155.0.0.2 netmask 255.255.255.0
Router1(config)#ip nat inside source list 1 pool nat_pool overload
Router1(config)#int gigabitEthernet 0/1 
Router1(config-if)#ip nat insi
Router1(config-if)#ip nat inside 
Router1(config-if)#exit
Router1(config)#int gigabitEthernet 0/0
Router1(config-if)#ip nat outside 
Router1(config-if)#exit
```

I still cannot ping my PC1 from my private network.
Between Router1 and Router2 I configured a static route.
I am able to ping from PC2 all the interfaces from Router1 and Router2.

Maybe someone can tell me please the correct steps how to configure my Router1 so that I can ping my PC1 from my private network ( PC2 ).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I answer my own question.

There were a few problems:

- router2 has not had a 'static' route to my public network
- I always thought I have to use as my nat pool the public network but I have to use any other public ip addresses.